# An uncountable PID with countably infinitely many prime ideals that is not a localization

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I was thinking of different ways of constructing a PID and found out that I don't know that many:

- a field (there are a few tricks for constructing fields e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794245/693936)
- a DVR (take the power series over a field or take Witt vectors of a perfect field)
- the ring of polynomials over a field.
- the ring of integers in some number fields.

Moreover one can localize any of the above at a multiplicative set. Only the third one and the fourth one can have infinitely many prime ideals and in characteristic $0$ the cardinality of the third one is equal to the cardinality of the set of its prime ideals. My knowledge is not sufficient to answer the following question

> Does there exist a characteristic $0$ uncountable principal ideal domain that has countably infinitely many prime ideals and that is not a localization of a PID with uncountably many prime ideals at a multiplicative set?

If one is allowed to use localization one can localize $\mathbb{C}[x]$ at the multiplicative set of elements that are not multiples of $(x-n)$ for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: this question was posted on MSE more than 48 hours ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3328117/693936) and has not received an answer yet.